# trying to make a file organiser. but all files are moving to same folder

Tags: python, python-3.x

this is the code i have written.
but everytime all files are moving to 'images' folder.
even in debugger,variables are all showing true values,but files are not moving according to if conditions

```
from os import mkdir,path,chdir,listdir
from shutil import move
filedirectory = '/root/Downloads'
chdir(filedirectory)
types = ['images','pdf','windows executables','linux tools','other scripts']
for type in types:
        if not path.exists(type):
        mkdir(type)
        files=listdir()
        for file in files:
            if path.isfile(file):
                lists = []
                lists = file.split('.')
                extension = lists[-1]
                if extension == 'jpg' or 'jpeg' or 'png':
                    move(file,'images')
                elif extension == 'exe':
                    move(file,'windows executables')
                elif extension == 'xz' or 'gz':
                    move(file,'linux tools')
                elif extension == 'py' or 'rb':
                    move(file,'other sripts')
                elif extension == 'pdf':
                    move(file,'pdf')
```

Comment: `if extension == 'jpg' or 'jpeg' or 'png':` does not work the way you think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point is, you're misunderstanding what `or` is and what it does at this line:

```
if extension == 'jpg' or 'jpeg' or 'png':
```

As `or` joins **boolean expressions**, the 2nd and 3rd "expression", which are two plain non-empty strings that evaluate to `True`, make the whole `if` statement always evaluate to `True`, so all your files are getting moved into `images`.

The correct way to achieve this is:

```
if extension in ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png']:
```

The same for other lines under.

As a side note, you probably want

```
extension = lists[-1].lower()
```

as various programs and devices (like a camera) generate files with uppercase names.

Comment: thanks. it worked. 
but plz clarify why didn't it worked before?

Comment: @rexon `extension == 'jpg' or 'jpeg' or 'png'` is interpreted as `(extension == 'jpg') or ('jpeg') or ('png')`. When string is evaluated into a boolean value, an empty one turns to `False` and a non-empty one turns to `True`. So your previous wrong code is always `True`.